# not be able to split dataset using recommender split in azure Ml studio

Tags: azure, recommendation-engine, azure-machine-learning-service

I am doing a crop recommender system using the Matchbox recommender system in Azure ml studio.
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLirz.png)

when I split data, it did not make the split. one dataset becomes full and another becomes null.

how to overcome this?

[this is the development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slLVh.png)

Comment: Please publish your project to azure gallery and share the link to your project to check.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken same dataset provided by you.

[image]

Performed Split data

[image]

This is my split data configuration

[image]

**Total records = 9**

After visualizing Dataset1, Number of records = 6

[image]

After visualizing Dataset2, Number of records = 3

[image]

Successfully split data.

Maybe you can **check split data configuration** with my split data configuration.

Comment: thank you for your effort. i need to split this dataset in recommender split. already it works in the rows split.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/split-data-using-recommender-split) to the document to Split Data using Recommender Split. We recommend that you review the walkthrough provided with this sample experiment in the Azure AI [Gallery](https://gallery.azure.ai/): [Movie Recommendation](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/3a02931f94114f47b4512dd9179b515e).